# How to integrate HTML template in express.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

How can include my html/js/css files in express.js?
Is there any way i can mange Template?

I want to use HTML only ( No jade).

```
    <head>
      <DATA>
    </head>
    <header>
         <?php include('includes/header.html'); ?>
    </header>
    <topnavigation>
         <?php include('top_navigation/header.html'); ?>
    </topnavigation>

    <content>
         <?php include('website/header.html'); ?>
    </content>

    <footer>
         <?php include('includes/content.html'); ?>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at some sample apps?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

[Follow this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)

in this tutorial `.ejs` template engine is used but you just replace `.ejs` to `.html` after that only one thing you need to change.

change this line:-

```
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

with this:-

```
 app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

thats all now you can use plain `html` pages for your template engine

Comment: There are many template options for Nodejs.  You should find one that you are comfortable with - there may be one that behaves like you see in PHP.  I used SWIG because it is based off of the Django system which I love...

Comment: @akaphenom i know there are many but he need plain html template engine which is not direct suported.

Comment: Sorry -  the comment was directed at the oringal poster. Not at your response - which is fine and therefore I didn't add another answer.  However I did want to convey the many options available.  Yes  ejs is one, but there are others such as SWIG.